# Where is location that Debug info (break point, etc) was stored in VS2013, native C++ dll project?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I want to know where is location that debug info was stored when I debugging c++ native dll project.

I have 2 project in my solution, C# managed project and C++ dll project. When I insert break point native dll, vs stops well in C#'s native calling with dllimport. And, I copied native dll to managed project directly (so managed project has native dll file only for native project, without pdbfile), vs stops breakpoint in native calling too! What makes this possible? managed project has no info for pdb file of native dll, but it seems that vs still can access native pdb file. Anyone can explain that?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the path to the PDB is stored in the DLL, and if it is not found, the debugging won´t start at all.

Comment: Have a look-see at the DLL with the dumpbin.exe utility.  Run it from the Visual Studio Command Prompt with the /all option.  You'll have little trouble finding the Debug Directory back, it contains the path to the PDB file.  That's how the debugger knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging an unmanaged dll is the same regardless of how the application was started (via .net or not). Wherever the dll is loaded from, Visual Studio will look for a .pdb file in the same directory and load that if it exists.

You can see when this happens in your output window (Debug->Window->Output). You will see a line like:

```
'<your-exe>.exe': Loaded '<path-to-dll>\<your-dll>.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

If you are writing a .net app though, none of this will happen if 'unmanaged code debugging' is turned off in your .net application project settings (Properties->Debug->Enable Debuggers)

Answer (score 0):

PDB loading follows a number of rules.  The first attempt of visual studio, is to assume the DLL was built on the debugging machine.  There is a fully qualified reference to the pdb in the dll.  That rule is firing.  Later on, it uses the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH variable, and can find multiple versions of a pdb from the same dll, if a symbol server is referenced.